# Use the Windows-key for another purpose in C#

Tags: c#, windows, delegates, windows-key

Is there a way to disable the standard built-in function of the Windows-Key (open the start-menu) and activate instead of that function for instance a delegate or an event in C#? I want to use this as an additional key in a full-screen app.

Comment: Maybe overriding the key down event and checking if it is the windows key?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think the OnKeyDown-method is called if the user uses the Windows-key. I think the solution will be closer to keyboard-hooking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hooks.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Comment: Is it possible that by using this method, you don't surpress the standard function of the Windows-Button, so that both functions (opening the startmenu, and the programmer-defined function) will be called.

Comment: A global hook (like the one specified) will suppress standard system functionality. An application level hook will not.